# SharePoint Online People Picker Returning External Email Addresses

Tags: sharepoint, azure-active-directory, exchange-server, sharepoint-online, peoplepicker

Previously in our tenant when using the People Picker within SharePoint Online lists, only internal users would be returned in the search results. Now people picker searches are also returning external email addresses. Even though the external emails are showing within the search results, they can't be selected.

I can't figure out where SharePoint is finding these external email addresses, I believe they have originally been entered via Outlook so they are potentially stored in Exchange, however I can't find any trace of where the external emails are being stored.

Can anybody please let me know where this information is being stored? Also is it possible to restrict SharePoint Online's People Picker search results to only return internal AD users?

[image]

Many thanks,

Alex

EDIT: Using F12 Dev Tools I have been able to ascertain that the internal users have a subclass of "OrganizationUser", whereas the external users have a subclass of "ImplicitContact". Now the question is: where is SharePoint storing/pulling Implicit Contacts from?...

Comment: How old is this account? The external accounts could be people the user interacted with in the past.

Comment: The account is over 6 years old, and yes that's certainly the case - I have emailed the external accounts via Outlook 365. Where are the external account details being stored, and how do I delete them and/or stop SharePoint from picking the info up?

Comment: I'm going to reach out to a PM to see where this is being stored. In the meantime can you try clearing your cache and deleting the cookies? This may clear up some things.

Comment: Great, many thanks James. I can confirm that the external users still remain after clearing my browsers cache & cookies. I have also tested this on two separate machines (which I know for sure that I have never sent an email to any external accounts on). Those machines still returned the external accounts through SharePoint, so I'm fairly confident that external accounts are being stored somewhere in the cloud, likely AAD or Exchange.